# VB Change Publisher with OneClick

Tags: vb.net, publishing, oneclick

Does anyone know how to change the publisher description with the VB One CLick? Or will I have to do a Windows Installer?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project Properties > Publish > Options > Description > Publisher Name